# Dependency Injection using value produced by @Produce

Tags: java, dependency-injection, java-ee-6, cdi, code-injection

I am new to CDI. I tried to Inject a String value to variable using @Inject,where the string is produced by a method annotated with @Produce.I refereed oracle Java EE 6,but for some reason my application cannot find the Produce method.

Class where I inject using @Inject

```
@Path("login")
public class Login{

@Inject
@Config
  private String name;
 //do somthing with String name
 }
```

My Producer Class

```
 import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;
 public class ConfigurationFactory {

  @Produces @Config
   public String getName() {
    return "XYZ";
   }
}
```

I used a Qualifier

```
@Target( { TYPE, METHOD, PARAMETER, FIELD })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Qualifier
public @interface Config {
}
```

I read in many post in stackoverflow and outside materials and Java EE 6 specifications.I followed this structure but I still get this error

```
org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no object available for injection at Injectee
```

I am not sure why this occurred,so I tried to analyze the problem and added a empty bean.xml file in under the WEB-INF directory and also I tried binding the resource file "ConfigurationFactory" using astractBinder .Any suggestion?

Comment: Which version of CDI are you using?

Comment: Version 1.0....this is my pom.xml dependency....                  <dependency>
 <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
 <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
 <version>1.0-SP1</version>
</dependency>  ....I run my app in tomcat 7,would that have anything to do with it,since I read in the below article Tomcat 7 doesnt support CDI well...Could you suggest  what can be done,http://www.brucephillips.name/blog/index.cfm/2011/3/13/Contexts-and-Dependency-Injection-With-Maven-and-Tomcat-7

Comment: Can you try adding scope (for instance `@RequestScoped`) to the `Login` bean?

Comment: I tried adding the @RequestedScope still getting the same error...i even try addign this:http://www.brucephillips.name/blog/index.cfm/2011/3/13/Contexts-and-Dependency-Injection-With-Maven-and-Tomcat-7....I really don't know what I am doing wrong here...